# Proof by induction: $2^{2n}-1$ is a multiple of $3$

Tags: induction, divisibility, solution-verification

I'm learning proofs by induction and I'm a little confused on how they work exactly. This is what I have.

Theorem: $\forall n\in\mathbb N_0$,  $2^{2n}-1$ is a multiple of 3.

**old proof with mistakes:**

> **Base:** $n=1$
>
> $2^{2(1)}-1 = 4-1 = 3$
>
> $3 = 3m, m\in\mathbb N$
>
> $3$ is a multiple of $3$, so the theorem holds for the base case.
>
> **Step:** $n\ge 2$
>
> Induction hypothesis: $2^{2n}-1:=3m, m\in\mathbb N$
>
> Induction conclusion: $2^{2(n+1)}-1=3m, m\in\mathbb N$
>
> $2^{2(n+1)}-1 = 2^{2n+2}-1$
>
> = $4*2^{2n}-1$
>
> = $4*3m$ by the induction hypothesis
>
> = $12m$
>
> = $3(4m)$
>
> $2^{2(n+1)} = 3m, m\in\mathbb N$

So $2^{2n}-1$ is a multiple of 3 $\forall\in\mathbb N$

Is the logic behind this correct?

**Edit: corrections:**

> **Step:** n ≥ 2
>
> Induction hypothesis: $2^{2n}-1=3m, m ∈ Z$
>
> Induction conclusion: $2^{2(n+1)}-1=3m, m ∈ Z$
>
> $2^{2(n+1)}-1 = 2^{2n+2}-1$
>
> = $4*2^{2n}-1$
>
> = $4*(2^{2n}-1)+3$
>
> = $4*3m+3$ by the induction hypothesis
>
> =$12m+3$
>
> $2^{2(n+1)}-1=3(4m+1)$

$4m+1\in\mathbb N$, so $2^{2n}-1$ is a multiple of 3 $\forall n\in\mathbb N_0$.

Comment: Close, but $4\cdot 2^{2n} -1 \ne 4(2^{2n}-1)$. Fix that and you have it.

Comment: What's $b$? Where is $m$ fixed and where is it not? Which $m$ did you pick to show the base case?

Comment: If interested, you can also rewrite this as: $2^{2n}-1=\left(2^2\right)^n-\left(1^2\right)^n=3\displaystyle\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} a^{2(n-j-1)} b^{2 j}$ or prove it by Little Fermat's theorem: $$2^2\equiv 1\pmod{3}\implies 2^{2n}\equiv 1\pmod{3}\iff 2^{2n}-1\equiv 0\pmod{3}\equiv 3\mid 2^{2n}-1$$

Comment: Hi @Christoph, b was a variable I made to replace 4m, as they both are integers. I just wanted to make the proof a little clearer. I'm a little confused on your other two questions, sorry. m = 1 in the base case. How would I represent when m is fixed vs when it's not?

Comment: By using words. A proof should be human readable in full sentences, not just a long list of mathematical symbols.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have applied the induction hypothesis wrongly. We have $4 (2^{2n}) -1=4 (2^{2n}-1)+3=4(3m)+3=3(4m+1)$

Comment: Thank you Kavi! I didn't catch that.

Answer (score 1):

### Long comment (due to the limited № of words in the comment section).

I don't know what your initial task was, but the statement holds for all the natural numbers and 0, i.e., $\forall n\in\mathbb N_0$. One might argue wether $0\in\mathbb N$ or $0\notin\mathbb N$, depending on the convention in your country, but for $n=0$:
$$\left(2^{2n}-1\right)\in\mathbb N_0.$$

You don't need to use $m$ in the base case because obviously $3\mid 3$ so it's redundant.
In the induction step I would say:
Let $3\mid 2^{2n}-1$ for some $n\in\mathbb N$.
If you use strong induction that I believe is unnecessary here, you would assume the statement:
$$P(n)\equiv 3\mid 2^{2n}-1$$
holds for all numbers in the set :$\{0,1,\ldots,n\}$.
Surely, $$n\in\mathbb N_0\implies n\in\mathbb Z, \forall n\in\mathbb N_0$$
because $\mathbb N\subset\mathbb Z$, but I wouldn't say $m\in\mathbb Z$ in this case so as to accent $m\in\mathbb N_0$ because $2^{2n}-1\ge 0\;\forall n\in\mathbb N$ so $m\ge 0$.
Once again, ' for some $m\in\mathbb Z$' is correct, but weaker, while:
$$\text{for some}\; m\in\mathbb N_0\:\text{is s stronger statement}$$

---

P.S.
You could've also written: $$2^{2n}=3m+1, m\in\mathbb N$$
in the assumption and substitute $2^{2n}$ by $3m+1$ in the step.